# How to get backend server dynamically in Angular if frontend and backend are on the same server

Tags: php, c++, node.js, angular, nestjs

I have a web application deployed on a local server

1. The problem is when I change The IP of the server I have to rebuild the angular application to assign the new IP.
   I solved it by making a JSON file and reading it to get the server IP but I still have to change the IP manually inside the JSON config file every time I change the server IP
2. When I publish the server from my local server to the internet I have the same issue because I have to use the public IP Of the Backend Server instead of the local IP

Can anyone help me to solve it?

Comment: you can serve the frontend from serverside

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the frontend into the server:

**first** change the url of the api in your angular project to /api
build your angular project 
`ng build // or ng build --prod // for  poduction`

for the **backend** (Nestjs): `install npm install --save @nestjs/serve-static`  to serve static files

**Finally** move the angular build output dist folder to the nestjs project with a different name like *frontend*

import the ServerStaticModule to the Appmodule

```
imports: [
ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
  rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'frontend'),
}),
],
```

then you can access to your application from the serve IP

for more details :

[Server Static nestjs doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static)

[Use nest as your server-side application with an Angular frontend](https://medium.com/@bo.vandersteene/use-nest-as-your-server-side-application-with-an-angular-frontend-540b0365bfa3)